# Java Collector.combiner getting called with supplier values always

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

Problem : Create a Collector implementation which would multiply stream of Integers in parallel and return Long.

Implementation:

```
public class ParallelMultiplier implements Collector<Integer, Long, Long> {

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Long, Integer> accumulator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (operand1, operand2) -> {
            System.out.println("Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (" + operand1 + ", " + operand2 + ")");
                                        long Lval = operand1.longValue(); 
                                        int Ival = operand2.intValue();
                                        Lval *= Ival;
                                        operand1 = Long.valueOf(Lval);
                                        System.out.println("Acc Updated : " + operand1);
                                        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(UNORDERED));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Long> combiner() {        
        return (operand1, operand2) -> {
            System.out.println("Combining Values : (" + operand1 + ", " + operand2 + ")");
                                        long Lval1 = operand1.longValue(); 
                                        long Lval2 = operand2.longValue();
                                        Lval1 *= Lval2; 
                                        return Long.valueOf(Lval1);
                                        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Long, Long> finisher() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Long> supplier() {      
        return () -> new Long(1L);
    }

}
```

Observed Output:

```
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 4)
Acc Updated : 4
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 3)
Acc Updated : 3
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 8)
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 6)
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 2)
Acc Updated : 2
Acc Updated : 8
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 5)
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 1)
Acc Updated : 5
Acc Updated : 6
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Accumulating Values (Accumulator, Element): (1, 7)
Acc Updated : 7
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Acc Updated : 1
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Combining Values : (1, 1)
Combining Values : (1, 1)
```

Invocation:

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        Collector<Integer, Long, Long> parallelMultiplier = new ParallelMultiplier();

        result = intList.parallelStream().collect(parallelMultiplier);
```

i.e. multiplication result is 1, where it should have been 8 factorial. I am not using 'concurrent' Characteristics either.
Ideally, i should have gotten multiplication result of substreams, fed into combiner() operation, but that seems to be not happening here.

Keeping aside the inefficient implementations of boxing/unboxing, any clue where I might have made mistake??

Comment: Java primitive wrapper are immutable and can't be used as accumulator.

Comment: You need a holder for your long accumulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collector is slightly off. Here is a simplified version(the why your does not work - see at the end):

```
 static class ParallelMultiplier implements Collector<Integer, long[], Long> {

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<long[], Integer> accumulator() {

        return (left, right) -> left[0] *= right;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<long[]> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            left[0] = left[0] * right[0];
            return left;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<long[], Long> finisher() {
        return arr -> arr[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<long[]> supplier() {
        return () -> new long[] { 1L };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class));
    }
}
```

You problems can be exemplified like this:

```
static Long test(Long left, Long right) {
    left = left * right;
    return left;
}

long l = 12L;
long r = 13L;

test(l, r);
System.out.println(l); // still 12
```

Comment: Thanks. So, what you are indicating is - the way to bypass immutable wrapper types is to use arrays of those types? I suppose this is working because 'left[0] = left[0] * right;' is returning a new Long obj that replaces the element in 0th place? Thx again for your test case. That helped!

Comment: @DevdattaK correct. You could see the same idea in `Collectors.summingInt` for example.

Comment: But, of course, there is no reason to use a `Long[]` for the container, when a `long[]` would do the same job without boxing overhead… By the way, the accumulator can be written as simple as `(left, right)-> left[0] *= right`

Comment: @Holger thank you. just edited. It's actually me being idiotic again, since `Collectors.summingInt` is *also* using `int[]`; could have paid more attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

As Flown stated, Java's primitive wrapper types are immutable and cannot be used as an accumulator.  Because you're computing the multiplication in parallel, we'll want to use a thread-safe implementation of a mutable `Long`, which is an `AtomicLong`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ParallelMultiplier implements Collector<Integer, AtomicLong, Long> {

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<AtomicLong, Integer> accumulator() {
        return (operand1, operand2) -> operand1.set(operand1.longValue() * operand2.longValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<AtomicLong> combiner() {        
        return (operand1, operand2) -> new AtomicLong(operand1.longValue() * operand2.longValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Function<AtomicLong, Long> finisher() {
        return l -> l.longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<AtomicLong> supplier() {      
        return () -> new AtomicLong(1);
    }

}
```

Testing this with what you've provided results in the correct answer, `8! = 40320`.

Comment: you don't even need to go `atomic` here. `Collectors.summingInt` does the same thing I've done via an array.

Comment: @Eugene Interesting, I guess both ways suffice.

Comment: You don't need to specifically support concurrency in a collector that collects elements from a parallel stream. If you do, it's fine, I guess, but having a concurrent collector (i.e. one which has the `CONCURRENT` characteristic) means that you can collect a parallel stream *concurrently*. I still don't know when I would need either one or the other.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yeah, I realized that after Eugene had posted his answer.  I was concerned that race conditions could arise, but I must be mistaken.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: well, if this collector had the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, it needed the `AtomicLong`, as it implies that only the accumulator will be called (concurrently), without using the combiner. Whether this has performance advantages or not (or even disadvantages), depends on the actual operation and context.